# Переполнение буфера в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, безопасность, buffer

Стоит ли переживать насчёт атак "переполнения буфера" в *WPF C#* и при условии что программа работает на *TCP* сокетах, то есть активное взаимодействие с сетью, что и опасно?

Я просто знаком с этим видом атаки и знаю, что в основном уязвимы программы, сделанные на чистом *C++* или *Qt* (если конечно, не уделить безопасности должного внимания). Ещё я читал мельком про *python*, но там (вкратце) говорят, что типа есть своя среда (или оболочка, точно не вспомню), ну и, короче, всё безопасно, а про *C#* ничего не слышал.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте вспомним, что переполнение буфера — это прежде всего ошибка программиста: он выделяет буфер одного размера, а читает в него данные большего размера. В результате данные затирают область памяти за буфером, то есть, обычно, системный стек.

Если вы не используете нативные компоненты, то можно особенно не беспокоиться. С .NET срыв стека получиться не может: среда выполнения не даст вашему коду получить доступ за границами массива, и вместо этого выбросит исключение.

Однако, ошибка, потенциально приводящая к срыву стека, может быть и в системной компоненте, и в библиотеке, и даже в компиляторе. Поэтому полной гарантии, к сожалению, нет.